# Symfony 4 swiftmailer configuration issues

Tags: symfony, smtp, swiftmailer

I have tried setting up SMTP in the dotenv file:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://mydomain.nl:25?encryption=tls&username=noreply%mydomain.nl&password=***`
```

And I've sent an email using `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send`. This gave me an error:

> [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host webmail.mydomain.nl [Connection timed out #110]`

So I assumed this is caused by the firewall. So then I tried to send an email via an online SMTP tester and the email got sent and all worked as expected.

However, this still does not work on my server. Even after turning off the firewall on my (Windows) VPS, the same error persists.

My setup is as follows:

- I have a VPS (WINDOWS) with plesk where I host my domain and the mail server.
- I also have a home server (CENTOS) where I host my subdomain with plesk.

What am I overlooking? What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using other ports? Maybe port 25 is blocked by your host/ISP.

Comment: in your `MAILER_URL` nothing provides the `webmail.` prefix shown in the error message. might be a typo, but if both the error message and your example are like that (I assume you "censored" your real domain, of course) you might need to clear the cache.

Comment: Have you had a look at your mailserver's log file - is there anything written to its log?

Comment: @Jakumi I mustve copied it wrong. I tried it with just the domain and with the webmail prefix. Both unfortunately no result

Comment: @NicoHaase The mail server logs do not show any errors. No logs show any errors other than the Symfony log saying that the connection timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, please correct me if im wrong. This is what I think I did wrong:

I have a subdomain from my main plesk which I host on my home server. The project i'm working on is running from there.

The main domain with that plesk account is running on a VPS with the mailserver.

As it turns out (I think) my ISP from my home internet has restricted access to port 25. And thats why my home server cant access the mail server.

I tried to disable firewalls everywhere, even routed the ports in my router to my home server, nil fix. (please note that i tried to telnet to several SMTP servers not just my own) with all access rejected.

I tried it with another port (465) from my home server and it works now.

At the end using another port did the trick. I am however not sure that this is the issue. But this is just my guess.

Comment: So you just posted :D anwser by yourself :D and tagged it as answer. Multiple people suggested to check with ISP for blockage. Most host providers block 25 port as it is unsafe and spam goes through it. Port 465 and 587 are for certified emails that uses TLS/SSL authentication so those ports are open, Ive had 465 port blocked also and only 587 left for usage.

Comment: I did reach out to my ISP. The ISP where my mailserver is hosted did not block port 25. However my website is hosted on another server where this port was blocked.

Comment: Well I believe we used ISP where it is out of context. We had Host Provider in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Some host providers block 465 and 25 port. So only 587 is left to use. First, contact your host provider and ask if they are blocking SMTP ports. And if not please come back with more information and server config.

Comment: I have checked with my provided. They do not block any ports. I also checked my error logs. PHP, APACHE, both have no errors in them. Only the Symfony log shows an error: `php.DEBUG: Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://webmail.mydomain.nl:25 (Connection timed out)`

Comment: Connection time out means you are blocked or service that supposed to listen is not working. Can you paste your smtp config?

Comment: I have made a screenshot from the plesk settings: [link](https://imgur.com/a/tBGjQKT) 

Also, maybe important is that when i use an online SMTP tester where i fill in the credentials, the same as used in symfony the email does get send.

Comment: What tester have you used? Have you checked your SwiftMailer with for example gmail smtp? Does it even work?

Comment: I have used [link](https://www.smtper.net/) tester. 

I tried to setup Gmail in Symfony4 and that send the email straight away.

Comment: Try using a client like Thunderbird test if it sends emails because I've had a similar issue that testers send an email and proper client is not. Check using a client like Thunderbird or Outlook. If the issue persists that means you SMTP configuration is wrong.

Comment: I tried to use another port (465) and that worked. I think my ISP from my home server blocked the ports? Even though my mailserver is on a VPS.